# What is the meaning of scope = scope-token *( SP scope-token ) scope-token = 1*( %x21 / %x23-5B / %x5D-7E ) in RFC6749 about OAuth2

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, rfc6749

What is the meaning of
`scope = scope-token *( SP scope-token ) scope-token = 1*( %x21 / %x23-5B / %x5D-7E )`

in [RFC6749  3.3. Access Token Scope](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-3.3)?

Answer (score 12):

so the way I interpret this is

```
scope-token = 1*( %x21 / %x23-5B / %x5D-7E )
```

seems to be saying that a *scope-token* can be 1 or more ascii characters from the defined hex character ranges. So basically x21 (!) to x7E (~) but disallowing x22 (") and x5C (\). See [here](http://defindit.com/ascii.html) for a list of characters and their hex codes.

and

```
scope = scope-token *( SP scope-token )
```

suggests that *scope* is a *scope-token* (as defined above) appended with zero or many `SP scope-tokens` where SP is a space character.

So a valid scope string would be:

```
scope = i am 5 scopes !!!!
```

but these wouldn't be valid scope strings:

```
scope = "scope1" "scope2" "scope3"
scope = scope1\scope2\scope3
```

Answer (score 4):

The expressions  are [ABNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form).

[RFC6749 8.1.  Defining Access Token Types](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-8.1) mentions it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this regular expression in a javascript snippet that test the `error_description` value of error responses on a OAuth2 server implementation, as `error_description` also requires those character constrains as per spec: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-5.2

```js
const regex = /1*[\x21\x23-\x5B\x5D-\x7E]/g
```